# Which nervous system is the Sensory system a sub-unit of?

Tags: human-biology

I'm wondering about this because on one hand, the actual sensory information from something such as sight or sound transmits to the brain, which is part of the central nervous system.

On the other hand, the actual muscles that control eye movement but have absolutely nothing to do with processing incoming information are part of the somatic nervous system, meanwhile the actual motion of tissues within sensory organs can also be involuntary.